# how to catch error(200)

Tags: python, exception, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get input from user, until he press ctrl-c. yet, I can't catch the
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYjZz.png), I think it has something to do with sklearn (I imported it for the rest of the code)

this is the code:

```
try:
    while(True):
        i+=1
        put = input("\tEnter name of feature number " + str(i) +":\t")
        features.append(put)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n\tFeatures Added!")
    sleep(SLEEP)
    return None
except:
    exit("\nError has occurred, please come back later...")`
```

Comment: Is the indentation in the question the same as in your code? you have the except blocks 1 indent level too deep.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your indentation as the following:

```
try:
    while(True):
        i+=1
        put = input("\tEnter name of feature number " + str(i) +":\t")
        features.append(put)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n\tFeatures Added!")
    sleep(SLEEP)
    return None
except:
    exit("\nError has occurred, please come back later...")
```